# mutliregional and multilingual website and url structure

Tags: seo, google-search, url, multilingual

I have a requirement to build multi regional site. Some regions will have more than one language, so this makes the site both mulitregional and multi lingual.

Client want to have one domain for all the region and to use region code in url. For example, in case of switzerland url will be xxx.com/ch/index. and when it comes to region with more than one language the url will be like xxx.com/ca/en/index for canada english and xxx.com/ca/fr/index for canada frech version.

But I would like to suggest slightly different url format. like, xxx.com/en-ca.index and xxx.com/fr-ca/index and in case of region with only one language, xxx.com/ch/index (switzerland).

Now, i would like to know on SEO perspective which approach will be advantageous?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

My favorite solution when it comes to multicountry/multilang domain/url structure within single domain is to use subdomains (better SEO).

BTW Switzerland speaks 4 languages, dominates German lang, then goes France, Italian and English lang.

I suggest to use this sctructure:

```
ch.xxx.com/en
ch.xxx.com/de
ch.xxx.com/fr
ch.xxx.com/it

ca.xxx.com/en
ca.xxx.com/fr

us.xxx.com/en
us.xxx.com/es

uk.xxx.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Google uses only the visible content of your page to determine its language. We don’t use any code-level language information such as lang attributes. You can help Google determine the language correctly by using a single language for content and navigation on each page, and by avoiding side-by-side translations. Translating only the boilerplate text of your pages while keeping the bulk of your content in a single language (as often happens on pages featuring user-generated content) can create a bad user experience if the same content appears multiple times in search results with various boilerplate languages.

Use robots.txt to block search engines from crawling automatically translated pages on your site. Automated translations don’t always make sense and could be viewed as spam. More importantly, a poor or artificial-sounding translation can harm your site’s perception.